# Expectation of time that combines both geometric and exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Suppose that there a number of water sources some with water and some dry. Assuming the at each such source there is a probability p that water has not run dry. Let N be the number of water sources that have to be searched before water is found. Suppose that the time T to search each source is follows T ~ Exp(λ). What is the expected time before water is found?

I know that N follows a geometric distribution such that $$E(N) = \frac{1}{p}$$
I also know that $$E(T) = \frac{1}{λ}$$
Am I correct to assume that the expected time to find water would be? $$ \frac{1}{pλ}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $J=\sum_{i=1}^N T_i$, where $N$ is the number of sources you search and $T_i$ is the time spent searching source number $i$. Then $J$ is the total time. We have the [tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation):$$\mathbb{E}[J] = \mathbb{E}_N\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N T_i\Bigg|N\right)\right].$$We first take expectation of the sum while holding $N$ fixed, then unfix $N$ and take expectation of that.

The inner expectation is $\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E}(T_i|N)=\sum_{i=1}^N 1/\lambda=N/\lambda$, and the outer expectation is $\mathbb{E}(N/\lambda)=\mathbb{E}(N)/\lambda=1/(p\lambda)$, as you said.